# jQuery Functions not Working After Using .load() to Refresh div Content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm reloading the contents of "**#some-div**" using "**.load()**" after processing some form data. This works just fine and "**#some-div**" is refreshed with the expected updated content. The problem is that none of my other assigned jQuery functions (e.g. "**.some-trigger**" below) will work for elements within "**#some-div**" after it has been refreshed. Any insight is much appreciated. Here's a simplified representation of my code.

```
<div id="some-div">
    <a class="some-trigger" href="#">I Won't Work Anymore After I've Been Refreshed</a>
</div>

<script> 
    $('.ajax-form').ajaxForm(function() {  
        $("#some-div").load(location.href+" #some-div>*","");
    });

    $('.some-trigger').someFunction();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should delegate the click event for dynamically loaded elements, try the following:

```
$("#some-div").on('click', '.some-trigger', function() {
   // do something here
})
```